# Redirect url using rewrite in web.config not working for some invalid characters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to provide a rewrite url rule in `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
     <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectToMainPage" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&apos;)+" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So, if I access `http://website.com/test"` then I will be redirected to `http://website.com/` (this is ok also for `'` character )

But, if I access: `http://website.com/test>` then I didn't get redirected to `http://website.com/` but 404 page is shown. (also for `<` symbol)

Why ?

Comment: `<` and `>` are [not valid url characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/542251)

Comment: And how to redirect to main page if those characters is met in url ?

Comment: Those characters should **never** be in the URL. What are you trying to do here? If someone sends a URL with invalid characters in it you should return an error code.

Comment: Bad people do that. No me...